# R Difference ets, holt, forecast.HoltWinters

Tags: r, forecasting

Currently I want to figure out the differences between the three forecasting methods ets, holt and forecast.HoltWinters. I already found some answers regarding the difference between ets and forecast.HoltWinters. However, I do not find anything for the holt (or ses, or hw) functions.

The results for ets and holt are very similar, but not identical whereas results for forecast.HoltWinters differs a lot.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you looked at `?holt` and `?HoltWinters`?

Answer (score 4):

**SES**: Simple exponential smoothing.
**Holt**: Exponential smoothing with a trend component, i.e double exponential smoothing.
**Holt-Winters**: Exponential smoothing with a trend component and a seasonal component, i.e. triple exponential smoothing.

There are variations of each of these 3 main methods, based on whether the components are additive or multiplicative and whether the error are additive or multiplicative.

ETS() is not, strictly speaking, a forecasting method, it is a function from the R Forecast package which is used to automatically select which one of the possible exponential smoothing models best fits your data. It is uses the state space representation to do so.

Answer (score 1):

ets is a group of models; with it you could run what is known as a Holt or a Holt Winters. Google "Rob Hyndman forecasting" to learn much more, but in summary there are 30 different ETS models where E=Error type, T=Trend type and S=Seasonality type (alternately, ExponenTial Smoothing). A few of these 30 have names based on who pioneered the technique.

Holt is a simpler method with no seasonality. Holt Winters has seasonality.